# Modeling a mobile app: How to go from the idea and design to classes and objects

Tags: android, ios, mobile, creation

I'm trying to develop my own application, I'm not too bad with code (Java, Objectif C...) nor design (Photoshop, illustrator... ).

But I always have the same problem, I never know how to go from my app Sketch and Storyboard to defining my objects and classes in code. It just makes a huge mess in my head.

I tried looking around but all the sites I can find describe the processus as Having an idea, creating a design, a storyboard, coding your app, publishing and marketing. But none explain how to go from the said storybord to the code or architectures of your code, thus not solving my problem.

As time passes it gets more annoying, I feel stuck :/.

Can you help me with any leads ? 
Pretty please with the sugar on top :)

Comment: For your case, you might have that kind of programmer's block syndrome since you're trying to juggle so much of the final design in your head. Sounds like you have a design-oriented mentality which is good. It might be helpful to work a bit bottom-up. Figure out a small component you need to make, make it, test it. Engineer it well, keep the coupling low, and it should integrate nicely into the final result. Work piecemeal like this and the challenge is putting it all together, but it'll prevent you from getting stuck and not getting too ahead of your implementation with your grand concept.

Comment: One thing I would suggest is bad is that you don't want some grand vision to leapfrog way ahead of where you're at in code. Some designers/product managers don't like to hear this, but I think you tend to get yourself into a rut far more often if you don't start coding sooner and allowing your design goals to somewhat evolve out of what you achieve in the code (having an interplay between execution and concept feeding off each other). Design, code, test, design more, code more, test more, etc. Iterate towards your final goals, and allow them to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Much insight and understanding can be gained from Apple Worldwide Developers Conference (WWDC) [videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/).

[Designing Great Apps](https://developer.apple.com/design/) highlights some videos and guides that may be helpful.

- **[Designing Intuitive User Experiences](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=211)**.  Learn about the key concepts and principles that will enable you to make your app more intuitive and approachable.

While one specific video may not cover all the practices you're looking to understand, the principles and recommendations that they present will set you on the right path, and bring you closer to your goal.

If you're not sure what videos to watch, try [ASCIIwwdc](http://asciiwwdc.com) to search session content.